# R utils::unzip() failing to unzip folder on windows only with error code -1

Tags: r, zip, unzip

Slightly less reproducible than ideal due to inability to share offending zip files

From a previous academic position I held, we created results in medium sized zip files (500mb-1gb). I'm now going back to analyse this data which means downloading about 100-200 such folders from dropbox, which lands as a .zip on my local machine.

As a first step to get at the data I then obviously want to unzip these folders, preferably not by hand.

Trying

```
zip_location <- "C:/path/on/my/windows/zipfile.zip"
utils::unzip(zip_location)
```

fails with

```
Warning message:
In utils::unzip(z) :
  error -1 in extracting from zip file
```

and also using the `zip` package fails with

```
zip_location <- "C:/path/on/my/windows/zipfile.zip"
zip::unzip(z)
Error in zip::unzip(z) : 
  zip error: `Failed to set mtime on `/` while extracting `C:/path/on/my/windows/zipfile.zip`` in file `zip.c:260`
```

Neither of which error codes turn up anything.

I also tried sending the same zipped folder to a friend who was able to unzip them without any pain, and I *am* able to unzip them on the same machine using python and `zipfile` e.g.

```
filepath = "C:/path/on/my/windows/zipfile.zip"
extract_dir = "C:/some/path"
with zipfile.ZipFile(filepath, 'r') as zip_ref:                                                                            
    zip_ref.extractall(extract_dir)
```

but I'd still like to try and understand the error codes for any future time where switching machines or programming language is not an option

for what its worth this is my session info in R

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] zip_2.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2
```

Comment: How much Ram do you have and how much is being used [htop on windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/815207/equivalent-to-the-htop-command-on-windows)? Probably red herring...

Comment: Does the simpler `utils::unzip(zip_location, list = TRUE)` work?

Comment: yup, `list = TRUE` runs through as expected and lists the contents correctly

Comment: 17GB allocated to R according to [benchmarkme](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/benchmarkme/index.html)